# How do I write a cron to copy and file to a local server?

Tags: php, bash, cron

I would like to set up a cron to copy a job from a URL to a server.

The cron command I am using is:

```
cd /home/username/public_html/bin/sh; /usr/local/php54/bin/php script.php;
```

The script.php file contains:

```
rm -f /home/username/public_html/filepath/file.zip; cd /home/username/public_html/filepath/; wget -q -O /dev/null "https://www.domain.com/file.zip"
```

But it is not working.

I would like to also REPLACE file `/home/username/public_html/filepath/file.zip` if it already exists.

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com are better places to ask questions about using `cron`. But you'll need to provide more information, like any error messages you're getting.

Comment: `script.php` isn't a PHP script, it'a shell script.

Comment: Thank you, there is no error which is coming back ... basically the script looks like it ran ok but then there is no destination file created so wondering what command and script I need.   I don't care really what kind of code is needed provided any regular shared server can handle it ... it's just making the file copy work.  many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open crontab to edit

   crontab -e
2. add line with you schedule like this (pls check desired schedule):

   */10 * * * * rm -f /home/username/public_html/filepath/file.zip; cd /home/username/public_html/filepath/; wget -q -O /dev/null "https://www.domain.com/file.zip"

cron will run every 10 minutes and delete file.zip than download new file.zip to /home/username/public_html/filepath/.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script has two modes:

1. Output straight to STDOUT (the default)
2. Execute PHP commands (what happens between `<?php` and `?>`

Your PHP script:

> ```
> rm -f /home/username/public_html/filepath/file.zip; cd /home/username/public_html/filepath/; wget -q -O /dev/null "https://www.domain.com/file.zip"
> ```

Is equivalent to the shell script:

```
echo 'rm -f /home/username/public_html/filepath/file.zip; cd /home/username/public_html/filepath/; wget -q -O /dev/null "https://www.domain.com/file.zip"'
```

… so it has no visible effect unless you look at the output from cron (probably emailed to you).

Those aren't PHP commands, they are shell commands. So execute the script using a shell and not with PHP.

```
cd /home/username/public_html/bin/sh; /bin/sh script.php;
```

… and consider renaming it to something less deceptive, such as `script.sh`.